# How to set a variable stop time in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

for a simulation in simulink i need a variable stop time.
The stoptime depends on a event in the simulation.
Is there a way to set the stop time to infinity and say stop,if the event is triggered?

greetings

Comment: Sure, there is a block named `Stop`. See [Stop Simulation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/stopsimulation.html).

Comment: thank you! and the stop time i can set to "inf" :=)